# Restart automatically after suspend

Tags: suspend

When I close lid of my laptop it suspends. But when I open lid - it boots like I turned it off and all my applications got closed automatically. And when it is in suspend mode led is blinking which shows that my system is suspended. I have checked the power setting where suspended is set as action for when the lid is closed on battery power as well as when plugged in. Where should I dig to fix this problem? I am using ubuntu is 17.04 
Thanks !!

Comment: Does this happen only if it has been suspended for some time, or even if you open it back up after only a few seconds?

Comment: It happens after some time (I guess 10-15 min)

Comment: I forget what it is called, but some recent intel chipsets have a feature where they have windows do a hybrid suspend where it is both hibernated and suspended to ram, and after a preset period of time in suspend, will just power off to save power and rely on the hibernate to resume.  You need to disable it.